# Print whole structure with single call (like JSON.stringify) in Java?

Tags: java

How to print any class instance in Java? Similar to JSON.stringify() in Javascript. Not necessary JSON, any format of output will do.

```
public class User {
    public String name, password;
    public int age;
    public ArrayList<String> phones;
    public static void login() {
        //do something
    }
}

User X = new User;
X.name = "john connor";
X.password = "skynet";
X.age = "33";
X.phones.add("1234567");
X.phones.add("7654321");

System.out.println(printClass(X))
```

Should output something like:

```
{ name:"john connor", password: "skynet", age: "33", phones: 
     ["1234567", "7654321"], login: void function() }
```

Comment: you specifically want json, or just a representation? ToStringBuilder from commons-lang does this.... altho not json

Comment: Any output format will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache's commons-lang's [`ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString%28java.lang.Object%29)

Of course, reflection is slow, so only do this with your test code. for normal use, please use eclipse's "Source" menu -> generate toString() (or intellij's generate toString()) which gives you a decent string.

Comment: reflection is not particularly slow. It's use here is perfectly fine.

Comment: thank you, this is what I want. but I found google gson, and since it prints Json which is more familiar to me, I use that.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many ways to achieve what you need. Though i would be interested in *why* you need.

1. Override the `toString()` method.

   see: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55
2. If the generation algorithm gets too long, then consider a separate class  say `UserPrettyPrinter`.

   ```
   public interface UserPrettyPrinter {
     string print(User);
   }

   public class PrintUserInJSON implements UserPrettyPrinter {
     string print(User user) {
       //implement the algo here
     }
   }
   ```

   you can also implement:

   ```
   public class PrintUserInXML implements UserPrettyPrinter {
     string print(User user) {
       //implement the algo here
     }
   }
   ```
3. Either in conjugation to *number-2* or as a standalone class, you can write

   ```
   public class PrintObjectBasicAlgo {
     String print(Object obj) {
       /* i write pseudo code here. just ask if you cannot implement this
       this would help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html

       Class class = Obj.getClass();

       Filed[] allVariables = class.getAllFieldsByReflection();

       ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>;
       ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>;

       for(Field field : allVariables) {
           Object value = reflectionGetValueOfField( field, obj );
           keys.add( field.getName());
           values.add(value.toString());
       }

       now that you have the keys and values, you can generate a string in anyway you like

       */
     }
   }
   ```
4. You may see [Visitor Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-visitor). it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. The simple one is just to override the `toString` function for your class. I dont see why you dont do this really. In this case its as simple as

```
String toString(){
    return "{ name:\""+name+", password: \""+passowrd....
}
```

The second option is to use reflection. This would be slightly (though not really) better if you had some sorta external class  used for "printing classes". The pseudo code for that would be

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuidler();
for(Field f : fields){
    s.append(f.getName() + "\" :\"" + f.get()+ "\"");
}
return s.toString();
```

However this would be costly as reflection always is. Also if you just properly override the `toString` functions in the first place your `printClass` function could literally just be

```
String printClass(Object o){ return o.toString();}
```

Which of course again begs the question of why do you need a `printClass` function?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Google Gson.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

```
class Project {
private int year = 1987;
private String name = "ROBOCOP-1";
private boolean active = false;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
  {
    add("PROTECT THE INNOCENT");
    add("UPHOLD THE LAW");
    add("SERVE THE PUBLIC TRUST");
    add("CLASSIFIED");
  }
};
}

public class GsonExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Project obj = new Project();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
}
}
```